# How to substitute facebook like button's href attribute with a link from json object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, facebook

On my page I have main div, which is generated by a plugin from a link. I'm getting this link by ajax call to simple json object. I need to substitute this link into the href attribute of mine XFBML FB Like button.

Here, what I've tried:

```
//application.js
 $.getJSON('/full/path/show.json?' function(data) {
                $('#maindiv').somePlugin(data.data_link);
               //some actions
    $('#facebook').attr('href', data.data_link);
            });

//index.html
<div id ='facebook'>
<fb:like href="" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
            </div>
```

But it doesn't upgrade the href attribute and just leaves my page's link by default. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know if I am getting it wrong but why is the tag in the div 'fb:like'? Shouldnt it be a link (a tag)?

Anyhow just set the href for the fb:like or a and NOT for the Div. Divs ussualy have no href attribute. :D

Should look something like this:

```
$('#facebook fb:like').attr('href', data.data_link);
```

---

As Shaun Hare said: you have to escape the colon. Just tested it. Works. Looks like this:

```
$('#facebook fb\\:like').attr('href', data.data_link);
```

---

If data link is a proper JSON object it should work this way. To update your link the code looks like this:

```
data = {data_link: 'http://example.com'};
$('#facebook fb\\:like').attr('href', data.data_link);
```

Of course you can get the JSON via AJAX. If it doesnt work please describe the problem precisely.

(PS: Dont use comments to ask new questions.)

Comment: I've started with that and it gave me no result, it was steel retrieving my page's link, not the requested.

Comment: 'fb:like' is the part of code, given by facebook [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Answer (score 2):

that because you are trying to get `href` from `div` which does not have one.
Have you tried giving the `fb:link` element an `id` and targeting that?

Update : apparaently you need to escape namespace - this works

```
alert($('#facebook fb\\\\:like').attr('href'));
```

Comment: what about target the child of the href  e.g. 
$('#facebook:first-child').attr('href')

Comment: Same, default link of my page.

Comment: Yes, now it targets right, thank you. But there is still a question of how to put `data.data_link` in the `href` properly. I've tried `<fb:like href="data.data_link" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" colorscheme="dark">`, but it just leaving the `data.data_link`

Comment: I updated my answer. Read this for help. Should work. (Dont use comments for new questions.)

Comment: I've marked it as answer. The link is upgrading, i see this through the source-code, but fb now still posting my home link, so I guess, that have to deal with it api on my own. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
//application.js
 $.getJSON('/full/path/show.json?' function(data) {
                $('#maindiv').somePlugin(data.data_link);
               //some actions
    $('#facebook').attr('href', data.data_link);
            });

//index.html
<div id ='facebook'>
<fb:like href="" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
</div>
```